# How to represent an octal value as its string representation

Tags: node.js, octal

I m looking for a way to display an octal value as its string representation.

IE,

```
stringified(0755)==='0755'
```

Where `stringified` is an hypothetic function doing the desired job.

My attempts to play with `parseInt(octal, <base>)` were not successful, i definitely miss something.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toString method for numbers has a radix parameter.

```
0755.toString(8)
```

Will return:

```
"755"
```

You can add the zero manually. For an example `stringified` function:

```
function stringified( number ) {
    return "0" + number.toString(8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But what to do with numbers like '0011' or '0001'?

You can use `padStart` method:

```
function stringified( number ) {
    return number.toString(8).padStart(4,'0');
}
```